# Error when using external dll .net framework in the reporting service 2014 report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-2014

I have a project developed in C# in Visual Studio 2008, NET Framework 3.5, SQL Server 2008 Standard with Reporting Service

I migrated to Visual Studio 2019, changed the target framework of all projects to net.framework 4.0,
and changed SQL Server to 2014 Standard with reporting Service

However, I'm having a problem with some reports that use a custom dll that was previously compiled in framework 3.5 and is now compiled in framework 4.0
When trying to deploy it gave the following message:

Error message:
"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error Error loading code module: 'DALPersisteDados, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'DALPersisteDados, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. 0"

I managed to work around the problem as follows:

In the Visual Studio report we reference the DLL compiled in the 4.0 framework
I copied the DLL compiled in framework 4.0 to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS

However, in the Reporting Service folder I left the DLL compiled in framework 3.5:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin

When I try to paste the 4.0 dll into the MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin folder, it returns the error message mentioned above

I checked the web.config of the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer folder, the reportin service seems to be
trying to use framework 3.5 and 2.0 I tried to change it manually but without success and I couldn't find anywhere how to make this change

Comment: Sql Server and Reporting Services are usually a full release behind Visual Studio. That is why those who develop both application code and Reports usually require two versions of Visual Studio. It could be that you have upgraded your projects to a .NET version that MSSQL Report Services is not yet ready to use. This may be related - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/reporting-services/net-framework-assemblies-sql-2014